# Equivalent function of ST_Buffer in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, polygon, geofencing

I am creating a road geofence using php/mysql. I have converted the road points lat long to Google Mercator projection. I need the equivalent function of [St_buffer()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) in Mysql. So that I can find all the coordinates of the polygon or help me how could I create the geofence?

Thanks!

Comment: ST_buffer ≈? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_buffer

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I have understood the question correctly but if I have:
`ST_Buffer()` has been introduced into [MySQL 5.6.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer)+ and [MySQL 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer).

> ```
> ST_Buffer(g,d)
> ```
>
> Returns a geometry that represents all points whose distance from the
>   geometry value `g` is less than or equal to a distance of `d`.